# React: Function in Parent Component not receiving data from Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project using React where I need to update the `state` of the Parent Component with the Child Component's input.  I did `console.log()` my way through each function in the chain and found that the `fetchText()` function in my parent component didn't receive the text

Here's what my parent component looks like

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { markdownText: `` };

    this.fetchText = this.fetchText.bind(this);
  }

  fetchText(text){
    this.setState({ markdownText: text });
    console.log(text);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="app-grid">
        <h1>Markdown Viewer</h1>
        <MarkDownComponent userInput={this.fetchText} />
        <PreviewComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Child Component looks like this

```
class MarkDownComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: ``};

    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
    this.sendInput = this.sendInput.bind(this);
  }

  getInput(event){
    this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
    this.sendInput();
  }

  sendInput(){
    this.props.userInput = this.state.text;
    //console.log(this.props.userInput);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="markdown-component">
        <textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={this.getInput}></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When `console.log()`ing `this.props.userInput` in the Child Component I get the value back as I type.  So that indicates the value is making it to the property, but why isn't it updating in the parent component?

Comment: Why do you assign `this.props.userInput` to  `this.state.text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to note here:

**you cannot change the value of props, it is passed to the component through it parent**

`this.props.userInput = this.state.text;`

this won't work.

So, to make fetchData of parent get the text from textarea you should do like this

`<textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={this.props.userInput}></textarea>`

and in parent component :

```
fetchText(event){
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({ markdownText: event.target.value });
}
```

you don't require functions like `getInput` and `sendInput` to send data to the parent component.

Comment: @Optiq hope its clear to you, what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are assigning state value to a function which is not correct.

```
this.props.userInput = this.state.text; // this is incorrect

//Right one

class MarkDownComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: ``};

    this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
    this.sendInput = this.sendInput.bind(this);
  }

  getInput(event){
    this.setState({ text: event.target.value });
    this.sendInput();
  }

  sendInput(){
    this.props.userInput(this.state.text);
    //console.log(this.props.userInput);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="markdown-component">
        <textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={this.getInput}></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can directly call this.props.userInput function in getInput function:

```
class MarkDownComponent extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: ``};

        this.getInput = this.getInput.bind(this);
      }

      getInput(event){
        this.props.userInput(event.target.value);
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div id="markdown-component">
            <textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={this.getInput}></textarea>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

ES6 way:

```
class MarkDownComponent extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: ``};
      }

      getInput = (event) => {
        this.props.userInput(this.state.text);
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div id="markdown-component">
            <textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={this.getInput}></textarea>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As told in the comments, there is no need to assign a state to your function. Also, if your desire is to change the text with a Child and nothing more you don't need a state in your Child. Don't use state if it is not necessary.

```js
class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { markdownText: "" };

    this.fetchText = this.fetchText.bind(this);
  }

  fetchText(e) {
    this.setState({ markdownText: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app-grid">
        <h1>Markdown Viewer</h1>
        Value is now: {this.state.markdownText}
        <MarkDownComponent userInput={this.fetchText} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MarkDownComponent = ( props ) => {
  return (
    <div id="markdown-component">
      <textarea id="editor" rows="16" onChange={props.userInput}></textarea>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```